When a boundary value problem for geodesics equation has a unique solution (is well posed)?
By a boundary value problem (bvp) for geodesics, I mean that I know two points between which a geodesic is spanned but I have no information about initial and final velocities in these points.
What properties a metric $g_{ij}$ and the boundary points $\vec{x}_{0}$ and $\vec{x}_{1}$ have to fulfill in order to have the unique solution to the boundary value problem? Or in other words the bvp is well posed?
E.g. on a sphere the bvp for geodesics is not well defined for two poles (as there is an infinite number of longitudinal lines running between them)
Can one answer this question in a general setting? Are there any theorems regarding the uniqueness of bvp?
In particular, is the solution to bvp for geodesics unique for conformal metric in flat two dimensional case, i.e when $g_{ij}=\phi(\vec{x})\delta_{ij}$, where $i,j\in\{1,2\}$, $\delta_{ij}$ is the Euclidean metric, and $\phi(\vec{x})$ is a differentiable (or smooth) scalar function?

It is possible to prove the following result of (pesudo)Riemannian geometry.
If $(M,g)$ is a smooth (pseudo)Riemannian manifold, then there is a topological basis made of convex normal neighborhoods.
An open set $U\subset M$ is said a  convex normal neighborhood if it is a normal neighborhood of every $p\in U$.
An open set $U\in M$ is said a normal neighborhood of $p\in U$ if there is an open neighborhood $V\subset T_pM$ of the origin which is starshaped such that $\exp_p|_V$ is a diffeomorphism from $V$ to $U=\exp_p|_V(V)$.
Collecting all together, we have the following result that answers your general question.
Every $q\in M$ admits a sufficiently small open neighborhhod $U$ such that, for every pair $p_1,p_2 \in U$ with $p_1 \neq p_2$ there is a unique (Levi-Civita) geodesic segment $\gamma :[0,1] \to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p_1$, $\gamma(1) =p_2$ and $\gamma([0,1]) \subset U$.
I stress that uniqueness holds only in each these  convex normal neighborhoods. When couples of points belong to two different normal covex neighborhoods we have, in general, two different geodesics joining them (*).
(Sorry, for the moment I do not have time to focus on your specific case).
Every good textbook on Riemannian geometry proves these facts. I also treat these issues in these lecture notes of mine  Chapter 7.

(*) This fact has some consequences also in rigorous QFT in curved spacetime and it was overlooked in important results https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11005-021-01464-4 https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.04903

the link to your lectures did not work for me on Edge (was implicitly requiring a chrome extension), but https://moretti.maths.unitn.it/manifolds.pdf worked

Thank you, I changed the link according to your address.

Thank you for your answer! This is very nice approach, but I was looking for something more applicable to determine if a geodesics I found solving the bvp is unique or not.
So in the spirit of your answer, I would have to look for a properties of $\phi$ in the definition of the conformal metric such that there exists a convex normal neighborhood large enough to fit the boundary points.
As a limit case, for the Euclidean metric, we can always find such a large enough convex normal neighborhood for any 2 points.
Do you have any suggestions how to tackle the answer for the conformal metric?
